# Value passed from flask to JS works in html, not in static

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I need to call a javascript function `say_hello` which exists in `static` folder and pass `Hello` as a message to be displayed as an alert. Here's what I do:

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', data={'message': 'Hello'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**This works:**

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    const message = {{data.message|tojson|safe}}
        alert(message);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/js/hello.js">
    const message = {{data.message|tojson|safe}}
        say_hello(message);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`hello.js`

```
function say_hello(message){
    alert(message)
}
```

The JS console doesn't show any issues, and the message is not displayed, just a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `<script>` tag has a `src`, its contents are ignored.  One or the other.

```
<script src="/js/hello.js">
</script>
<script>
    const message = {{data.message|tojson|safe}}
        say_hello(message);
</script>
```